# Не запускается OpenServer Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows

```
2017-01-16 21:22:27  --------------------------------------------
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление Hosts файла
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.5
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление конфигурации PHP-7.0
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Обновление конфигурации Apache-2.2
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Запуск MySQL-5.5
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Запуск Apache-2.2
2017-01-16 21:22:27  Проверка состояния сервера
2017-01-16 21:23:01  Не удалось запустить Apache-2.2
2017-01-16 21:23:01  Сбой запуска!
2017-01-16 21:23:01  --------------------------------------------
2017-01-16 21:23:01  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2017-01-16 21:23:01  Остановка системных модулей
2017-01-16 21:23:03  Отключение виртуального диска
2017-01-16 21:23:03  Сервер успешно остановлен за 1,297 секунд!
```

Answer (score 1):

Закройте апаче и затем запустите от имени админа.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках выберите вместо Apache-2.2 -> Apache-PHP-7 и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете версию `php 7` то вам нужно в настройках поставить версию апач `Apache-PHP-7` и позже.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрим логи после неудачного запуска. В настройках Open Server - Модули - нужно выставить версию apache-2.4 x64 (на какую ссылается лог в соответствии с разрядностью системы). Мне только это и помогло.

Answer (score 0):

При сообщении - Файл C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts недоступен для записи. Отключите использование HOSTS файла или настройте права доступа
Сбой запуска!
- выполни следующие действия: 
        -правой кнопкой по иконке опенсервера и выбираешь "выход",
        -правой кнопкой по иконке опенсервера и выбираешь "запуск от 
         Администратора" - запускаешь.

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте в настройках версию `Apache` больше чем `2.4`